# Get the values from a histogram or the values from a trace

Tags: plotly, histogram, plotly-python, plotly-express

In plotly I can create a histogram as e.g. [in this example code from the documentation](https://plotly.com/python/histograms/):

```
import plotly.express as px
df = px.data.tips()
fig = px.histogram(df, x="total_bill")
fig.show()
```

which results to:
[image]

My question is how do I get the data values of the histogram? From what I can think of, this question should be equivalent to how do I access the values of a trace? (google did not help with either)

I could use numpy to redo the histogram:

```
import numpy as np
np.histogram(df.total_bill)
```

But this will not always result to the same buckets, plus it is re-doing all the sometimes expensive computation that goes to create a histogram.

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

My understanding of your question is that you would like to get the exact intervals and counts displayed in the histogram. For smaller subset of `px.data.tips()`, this:

[image]

And reading off the chart those values would be:

```
counts = [2, 4, 3, 1]
bins = [5, 15, 25, 35, 45]
```

There's no *direct* way to do this, but that doesn't mean it's impossible. At least if you're willing to use the awesome `fig.full_figure_for_development()` and a *little* numpy.

#### Code highlights *(complete snippet at the very end)*

```
xbins = f.data[0].xbins
plotbins = list(np.arange(start=xbins['start'], stop=xbins['end']+xbins['size'], step=xbins['size']))
counts, bins = np.histogram(list(f.data[0].x), bins=plotbins)
```

#### Output:

```
[2 4 3 1] [ 5 15 25 35 45]
```

#### All the details:

What I'm guessing you would *like* to be able to do is this:

Run:

```
fig.data[0].count
```

And get:

```
[2, 4, 3, 1]
```

But the closest you'll get is this:

Run:

```
fig.data[0].x
```

And get:

```
[15.53, 10.07, 12.6 , 32.83, 35.83, 29.03, 27.18, 22.67, 17.82,
   18.78]
```

And those are just the raw values from the input`df['total_bill'].tail(10)`. So DerekO is  right in that the rest is handled by javascript. But [`fig.full_figure_for_development()`](https://community.plotly.com/t/announcing-plotly-py-4-10-date-axis-improvements-a-faster-px-imshow-and-full-figures-for-development/44685) will:

> [...] return a new go.Figure object, prepopulated with the same values
> you provided, as well as all the default values computed by Plotly.js,
> to allow you to learn more about what attributes control every detail
> of your figure and how you can customize them.

So running `f = fig.full_figure_for_development(warn=False)`, and then:

```
f.data[0].xbins
```

Will give you:

```
histogram.XBins({
    'end': 45, 'size': 10, 'start': 5
})
```

And now you know enough to get the same values in your figure with a little numpy:

#### Complete code:

```
import plotly.express as px
import numpy as np

df = px.data.tips()
df = df.tail(10)
fig = px.histogram(df, x="total_bill")
f = fig.full_figure_for_development(warn=False)

xbins = f.data[0].xbins
plotbins = list(np.arange(start=xbins['start'], stop=xbins['end']+xbins['size'], step=xbins['size']))
counts, bins = np.histogram(list(f.data[0].x), bins=plotbins)
print(counts, bins)
```

Answer (score 7):

In the same Plotly Histogram documentation, there's a section called [Accessing the counts yaxis values](https://plotly.com/python/histograms/#accessing-the-counts-yaxis-values), and it explains that the y values are calculated by the JavaScript in the browser when the figure renders so you can't access it in the figure object (for example, through `fig.layout` or `fig.data`, which you might try for other types of charts)

They recommend calculating the counts and bins yourself using `np.histogram`, then passing these values to `px.bar` to ensure that your histogram matches the buckets as you intend.

Answer (score 0):

After making some proofs, I came to the conclusion that you can get histogram values in y axis by using groupby. You can generate your own dataframe with total_bill values and count for each one of the values like this:

```
import plotly.express as px
df = px.data.tips()
fig = px.histogram(df, x="total_bill")
fig.show()
print(df.groupby('total_bill').total_bill.agg('count').to_frame('COUNT').reset_index().head())



          total_bill  COUNT
 0          3.07      1
 1          5.75      1
 2          7.25      2
 3          7.51      1
 4          7.56      1
```

I guess plotly does something similar, and then add some other grouping to stack values in a certain range together in each one of the histogram bars.