# How can I print and hover the percentage of each bin in Plotly Python (go.Histogrm())?

Tags: python, plotly, data-visualization, histogram, plotly-python

This is my plot where there are 3 hover values in a bar (although this is a histogram) and one of the hover info is called **Count**. My question is how can I add a percentage value ((count of **N** class/count of **N** class + count of **Y** class)*100) into the hoverinfo of each bin? Maybe we can put the hoverinfo just right after the hoverinfo of `EarlyClaimedAndLapsed: N (& Y)`.

```
lapsed_df = claim_df[claim_df['EarlyClaimAndLapsed']=='Y']
non_lapsed_df = claim_df[claim_df['EarlyClaimAndLapsed']=='N']

for con_col in claim_df.select_dtypes(include = ['number']).keys().tolist():

    fig = go.Figure()
    fig.add_trace(go.Histogram(x = non_lapsed_df[con_col], name='N', marker_color='blue', hovertext=non_lapsed_df['EarlyClaimAndLapsed']))
    fig.add_trace(go.Histogram(x = lapsed_df[con_col], name='Y', marker_color='red', hovertext=lapsed_df['EarlyClaimAndLapsed']))
    fig.update_layout(title=f'{con_col} vs EarlyClaimAndLapsed', title_x=0.5, barmode="overlay", 
                      legend_title='EarlyClaimAndLapsed', xaxis_title=f'{con_col}', yaxis_title='Count'
                     )
    fig.update_traces(opacity=0.5, nbinsx=10, histfunc='count', hovertemplate="<br>".join([
            f"{con_col}"+": %{x}",
            "Count: %{y}", 
            "EarlyClaimAndLapsed: %{hovertext}"
    ]))
    fig.show()
```

[image: Count of ENTRY_AGE - N]

For instance, we can see that for the ENTRY_AGE group **range from 20-29** has the highest frequencies where **N have *3032*** while **Y have *1268***. So, the percentage calculation for **N** and **Y** for this group of ENTRY_AGE would be **(3032/(3032+1268))*100=70.51%** and **(1268/(3032+1268))*100=29.49%**

[image: Count of ENTRY_AGE - Y]

**Note:** Reason why I use Histogram is because these features (there are other numeric features aside from **ENTRY_AGE**) are numeric features.

Aside from putting the percentage details into the `hoverinfo`, can we also display the percentage details on each bin of the histogram? Just like the image shown below:

[image]

Comment: Can you include a [mcve]? Perhaps code for a single barplot (not Image of the code)

Comment: The [normalization setting](https://plotly.com/python/histograms/#type-of-normalization) can be added to the histogram, so add `histnorm='probability density'` to the histogram. If you want the y-axis to display frequency values and the hover to display percentages, you must prepare custom data with calculated percentages and specify them in advance. `hovertemplate="Per: %{y:.1%}")`

Comment: @Steve I have added my codes that used to print the Histogram.

Comment: I've been playing with a slightly long-winded solution, where the hover text is customised as a separate string - you could do this with an answer to [plotly:get the values from a histogram / plotly:get the values from a trace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66583626/plotlyget-the-values-from-a-histogram-plotlyget-the-values-from-a-trace).