# Different histograms for plotly and matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, plotly-python

Both of these libraries produce different results. Considering that matplotlib histogram uses `np.histogram`, it's more likely that plotly histogram is wrong. The problem persists even if I change my data or the way I display it.

That's not even mentioning that plotly doesn't care about `nbins` parameter and uses its own logic.

matplotlib:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import plotly.express as px

df = pd.DataFrame([np.arange(1,20,1), [1,1,5,8,12,15,19,19,1,1,1,8,8,5,3,2,7,5,2]]).T
plt.hist(df, bins=10, histtype='barstacked', ec='k') 
plt.show()
```

[image]

Plotly:

```
fig = px.histogram(df, nbins=10, height=400, width=500)
fig.update_traces(marker_line_color='black',
                  marker_line_width=0.5)
fig.show()
```

[image]

(Though, for this particular example, number of bins matches. If you try to set it to 12, plotly will still use 10.)

Comment: The only difference is where the bin edges are drawn, and clearly plotly and matplotlib do the bin edges differently. plt.hist - array([ 1. ,  2.8,  4.6,  6.4,  8.2, 10. , 11.8, 13.6, 15.4, 17.2, 19. ]). You can hover over the plotly figure to see what values are in each bin.

Comment: Probable duplicate of matplotlib: [Getting information for bins from the histogram function](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19442224/7758804) and plotly: [Get the values from a histogram or the values from a trace](https://stackoverflow.com/q/66583626/7758804)

Comment: @TrentonMcKinney if we get the same plots then i don't follow your idea of difference in drawing bin edges, because there's clearly different number of elements within some bins, last 5 bins are ok but first ones are complete disaster (i added plots in case something is interfering with out results), please elaborate on that

Comment: I ran the code and looked at the plots prior to posting my first comment. The values in each plotly bar are `0-1, 2-3, 4-5, 6-7, 8-9, 10-11, 12-13, 14-15, 16-17, 18-19`, whereas `plt.hist` edges are `array([ 1. , 2.8, 4.6, 6.4, 8.2, 10. , 11.8, 13.6, 15.4, 17.2, 19. ])`  from 1 - 2.8, the count is 2, from 0-1 (in plotly) the count is 1, etc.

Comment: @TrentonMcKinney now i get it, thank you, apparently plotly starts not from minimum value, but from zero in case of positive numbers, i ran the same code but changed one number to -5 and plots are the same

Comment: I think [labels on each bin edge](https://i.stack.imgur.com/POatM.png) makes it more obvious: `d = plt.hist(df, bins=10, histtype='barstacked', ec='k') ` and `plt.xticks(d[1])`. I could not find and easy qucik way to do this with plotly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are both correct, but the automatic choices of the bins are different.

In such situations (integer values or low number of values per bin) it's best to choose the bins explicitly.

focus on the example where you divide the 19 numbers [1,2,3,...,17,18,19] into 10 bins. Both library ensure, that the leftmost and rightmost bins are used at all, and that the bins are equally sized.

In plotly, the mouse over hints display the different ranges.
In matplotlib the x-value of the cursor displayed when hovering shows you the borders between the bins.

The different choices are more likely to give the same results, if you have a large number of noisy input values, like random experiments or measurements.

Comment: actually this is a simplified example to show the difference in plots, i have 2 files with 15 thousand of values each and i tried bins up to 50 and in most cases the plots are basically mirrored, and i don't quite get the part about different binning, isn't it just Minimum value + min/bin_size up until Maximum value?